# Calling a Java program in Ruby and getting output

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want my Rails app to call a Java program to do some labor-intensive work. What's the best way to get the output from the Java program into Ruby? The output is text, about 60,000 chars per query.

Is there a better way than writing/reading from textfiles?

I don't want to use JRuby.

Comment: Does "labor-intensive" mean you want it to happen asynchronously?

Comment: I think he means the java program does a lot of repetitive work.

Comment: No need for asynchronous execution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
output = %x{java your_program.java}
```

Comment: Nice. Thanks @texasbruce, just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on scale. It could be worth actually setting up a messaging protocol such as [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/). 

If you are just setting up a monitor or other script driven process, you could look at ruby's  [IO.popen](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html#method-c-popen), but that would still leave you parsing text streams.